# Contents overflowing outside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 blocks and it has some content, all of them are overflowing the text so i used

```
overflow:hidden
```

it works fine but when we remove this line it clearly shows that text is overflowing outside the `<div>` as i am using marquee for scrolling the content, contents are actually coming out side of `<div>`

My fiddle :  https://jsfiddle.net/qtdod55s/

```css
.leftcolumn {
  background-color:darkgrey;
  height:320px;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  border-color:black;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:thin;
  color:white;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.rightcolumn {
  padding:10px;
  height:320px;
  margin:10px;
  border-color:black;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:thin;
  color:white;
  /*overflow:hidden;*/
  display: inline-block;
}

#tv {
  background-color:black;
  margin:10px;
  height:200px;
  margin-bottom:2px;
}

#weather {
  background-color:darkgrey;
  margin:10px;
  height:120px;
  margin-top:1px;
  border-color:black;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:thin;
}

#wethericon {
  font-size:100px;
  margin:10px;
  color:yellow;
}

body {
  font-size:18px;
  font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

p {
  height:100%;
}


thead {
  background-color:green;
}

tbody {
  background-color:silver;
  color:black;
}

.table-responsive {
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

.h3, h3 {
  color:red;
  /*font-weight:bold;*/
  margin-bottom:10px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7 leftcolumn">
      <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" scrollamount="2">
        <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 rightcolumn">
      <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XnwYWcA5ULk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7 leftcolumn">
  <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" scrollamount="2">
    <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
  </div>
<div class="col-md-4 rightcolumn">
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" scrollamount="2">
    <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it
    to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing


    <h3>Pending Inspection Checklist</h3>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table" id="ins-checklist">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Team Name</th>
                    <th>Total </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


    <h3>Pending Work Completion Report</h3>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table" id="work-completion">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Team Name</th>
                    <th>Total </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</marquee>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/ajaxcalls.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Apply `height: 100%` for `marquee`. See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/1a8hk69e/)

Comment: Working fine brother

Comment: Close all the `<p>` tags as well.

Comment: `.rightcolumn` remove comment of `overflow:hidden `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding below code to css worked fine for me

```
marquee {
  height: 100%;
}
```